# Import custom MIB PySNMP Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

I have already converted the `CISCO-VTP-MIB` to work with PySNMP, but I am unable to import it.

All the help online is for *nix machines. How can I import this module to use in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To point PySNMP to a place where you keep Pythonized MIBs, use [ObjectIdentity.addMibSource()](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#custom-pysnmp-mibs-location).

But a better approach (at least for SNMP manager apps) is to let PySNMP compile ASN.1 MIB file into whatever form it needs. For that you just need to point it to a location where it could find ASN.1 MIBs. You could do the latter with [ObjectIdentity.addAsn1MibSource()](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#custom-asn-1-mib-path).

Speaking of Windows paths, PySNMP does not do anything special about them. I guess you could just follow Python customs in that regard. For instance, `c:\mibs` in Python parlance might look like `c:/mibs`.